# Проблема с передачей данных из формы (MVC)

Tags: java, html, spring, mvc

Уважаемые, столкнулся с проблемой, не могу никак её решить. Имеется форма, из неё данные идут на добавление и обновление. Из jsp в контроллер. Проблема заключается в том, что данные на добавление проходят без проблем, но когда пытаюсь обновить, сталкиваюсь с ошибкой 404 Bad request.

**The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).**

Как я понял, поле id летит со значением null, что соответственно вызывает ошибку. Так же, через дебаггер увидел, что запрос до контроллера не долетает. Что посоветуете?

students.jsp

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/students/add"/>

<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="student">
<table>
    <c:if test="${!empty student.name}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="id">
                    <spring:message text="ID"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8" disabled="true"/>
                <form:hidden path="id"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="name">
                <spring:message text="Имя"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="name"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    ...

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <c:if test="${!empty student.name}">
                <input type="submit"
                       value="<spring:message text="Изменить студента"/>"/>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${empty student.name}">
                <input type="submit"
                       value="<spring:message text="Добавить студента"/>"/>
            </c:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

StudentController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student){

    this.studentService.addStudent(student);

    return "redirect:/students";
}
```

База

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте логи сервера, найдите полный stack trace исключения и скопируйте его текст в вопрос.

Comment: Проблема решена. Заключалась она в дате. Передавать дату я могу только в таком виде: 01/01/2001. Когда форма автоматически заполнялась значением, оно было вида 01-01-2001. Глупое упущение.

Может кто подсказать, какими средствами можно расширить, скажем так возможности ввода даты?

Comment: Вам помогут [конвертеры и форматтеры](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#core-convert).